# Node.js Formidable upload entire directory

Tags: javascript, forms, node.js, fs, formidable

I've been playing around with node-formidable and it's great for uploading & handling single files. This is my code so far:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    files = [],
    fields = [];

form.uploadDir = __dirname+'/../public/content/images/';
var thumbnailDir = __dirname+'/../public/content/images/thumbnails/';

form
  .on('field', function(field, value) {
    fields.push([field, value]);
  })
  .on('file', function(field, file) {
    files.push([field, file]);
  })
  .on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
    var onePercent = (bytesExpected / 100);
    var percentageUploaded = (bytesReceived / onePercent).toFixed(0) + '%';
    console.log(percentageUploaded);

    io.sockets.emit('uploadpercentage', { percentage: percentageUploaded });

  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('-> upload done');
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('received fields:\n\n '+util.inspect(fields));
    res.write('\n\n');
    res.end('received files:\n\n '+util.inspect(files));

    /* Go through each file and save it, then resize it and save thumbnail version */
    files.forEach(function(file) {

        /* Get the file contents, which are stored in the 2nd value of the array */
        var fileContents = file[1];

        /* Setup path variables */
        var filePath = form.uploadDir + fileContents.name;
        var thumbnailPath = thumbnailDir + fileContents.name;

        /* Rename the image to the original filename */
        fs.rename(fileContents.path, filePath, function() {

            console.log('Its saved & renamed!');

            /* Imagemagick - make thumbnails */
            im.crop({
                srcPath: filePath,
                dstPath: thumbnailPath,
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                quality: 1
            }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });

        }); /* End of rename function */

    }); /* End of for statement */

  });

  /* Parse the form */
  form.parse(req);
```

Ideally what I'd like to do is to be able to drag & drop a directory into the files[] input, and handle the folder and all of it's contents with Node.js. Is this possible with formidable? If so, how is it done and if not, are there any alternative methods I could look at for doing this?

If I try uploading a folder as it is at the moment, I get the following error message:

```
Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = PART_DATA
```

Thanks for any help